# System Date.Time conversion in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I convert this system generated DATE.TIME format in Excel into Date and Time (much more readable to a user)?

2111031439

i.e. yy/mm/dd:hr/mm

Date time should be:

21 11 03 14:39

YY MM DD HR:MM

Many thanks

Comment: Change the cell's format to your desired format.

Comment: Exactly how was that generated?

Comment: The number as shown does not readily format to date or time - That is, not recognizable by Excel

Comment: And what should the date/time be with that number?

Comment: It was legacy system generated, when I do an extract from the system I get this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number is an integer, and assuming it is in the desired time zone and in this century, you can convert it with the formula:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"\2\000\/00\/00 00\:00")
```

This will result in an Excel Date/Time and appear as something like `44503.61042`.  You can then format the cell to whatever date format you want.

If the number is a "real date" that happens to look as it does due to formatting, then merely change the formatting.

Comment: I tried setting a custom format as `yy/mm/dd hh:mm`, but it shows in Excel as `###...###`

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @spikey_richie That's because it is an integer and not an Excel DateTime. That being the case, any values > ≈ 2,958,465 will overflow Excels maximum date and result in the `#####...`'s